# Interop C# with parameter of type VT_USERDEFINED

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, com-interop

I try to call from C# a COM method that require that a parameter of type `VARIANT` is defined as `VT_USERDEFINED` (it also accept other types, but it have a special handling of `VT_USERDEFINED`).

The interface is:

```cpp
    HRESULT GetRecord(
        [in] VARIANT varKey,
        [out] VARIANT* pvarRecord);
```

The question is how to call this method from C# where `varKey` is an integer defined as `VT_USERDEFINED`.

The COM interop DLL is generated by **tlbimp.exe** from the idl file in C++.

**Edit 1**
The code on the C++ side is like this:

```cpp
    if (varKey.vt == VT_USERDEFINED)
    {
        // Sequential record number given
        UINT uintRecordNumber = varKey.uintVal;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This link might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-objects

Comment: Nothing on that page mentions handling for `VT_USERDEFINED`

Comment: Does this work `void GetRecord(object varKey, out object pvarRecord)` and `PreserveSig=false` (or you can return `int` and set `PreserveSig=true`) I suppose it depends what exactly you want to pass in here

Comment: @paulsm4 I have seen that page, but it don't help me. It don't say anything about ```VT_USERDEFINED```

Comment: VT_USERDEFINED is not a COM Automation data type, it's not supported by .NET, you'll have to redefine a VARIANT structure of your own and/or pass IntPtr and anyway do the work by yourself. Or use another VARIANT type, like VT_RECORD.

Comment: @SimonMourier I know that it is no automatic handling of that type in .NET. The question is how I can do it manually myself as you describe it.

Comment: It's not clear what you know. You can't use tlbimp.exe. You mention "an integer", what's the relation with VT_USERDEFINED? Are you sure the native side is really using VT_USERDEFINED? Looks very unusual. Can you show us your C++ side?

Comment: @SimonMourier Sorry, was not meant to be rude, English is not my first language. I have updated the question with what it looks like on the C++ side. I agree that this is a strange handling.

Comment: The C++ code is completely wrong, it shouldn't use VT_USERDEFINED. Can you change it?

Comment: @SimonMourier I have contacted him who is responsible for the code and hope he changes it.